Can I have a vacation to Canada, while living in France for 3 months?
I am from Korea. I am both a French and Korean citizen. I got to France 3 months ago and am planning to visit my friend in Canada during this vacation. I don't know how to speak French. Is the trip possible?

What is your question more specifically? Whether there are planes from France to Canada? Whether you need specific documents or authorisation? Whether you need to speak French to be able to enjoy Canada? Why are you concerned?

Where in Canada?  The situation definitely changes based on location.

Speaking French is not a requirement for visiting Canada. In most of Canada they hardly speak it at all and even in the French speaking area(s) you can survive without French.
In Quebec they speak a different version of French from France, so speaking French the Paris way while helpful is not always making life easy.
As a French citizen you need to apply for an Electronic Travel Authorisation (ETA), if you are approved for that you do not need more.
